# RunWorkerCompleted firing too late after all the statements are done executing in DoWork event handler

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have huge sum of records to be written to the DB which can take upto 1 hour (done in the `DoWork` of `BackgroundWorker`) and in the mean time I want to display a progressbar to the user.

I am updating `progressbar` based on the number of records already written and as soon as the `RunWorkerCompleted` gets fired, I want to close that progressbar form and display some diagnostic stuff on the main form to the user.

At the moment, everything works like a charm except that after all of the statements that are executed in the `DoWork` event handler, the `RunWorkerCompleted` fires like **123 seconds after**.

My questions is what is causing this delay?

Comment: You should show some code. There is no natural delay. It has something to do with your programming

Comment: Its highly unlikely its a bug in the *.net BCL*, so all that's left is your code and we cant see it

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your code as Romano pointed out.  [mcve]